# Jinja2: Add new key/value items inside a for loop statement

Tags: for-loop, jinja2

I want to append new key/value item to a hash inside a jinja2 for loop. Until now i have only been able to append a static entry, but i would like to add a test depending on the current element.

My data set looks like:

```
people:
   - forename: John
     name:     Doe
     gender:   M
   - forename: Jane
     name:     Doe
     gender:   F
```

I want to dump something like:

```
Hello  Mr John Doe
Hello  Ms Jane Doe
```

I can do something like :

```
{% for person in people -%}
  Hello  {{ 'Ms' if person.gender=='F' else 'Mr' }} {{ person.forename }} {{  person.name }}
{% endfor -%}
```

but i find this syntax awkward, especially if i have to repeat the test many times.

My idea is to add a *title* key to my data and i am trying to do it inside the for statement.

Jinja accept the *combine* filter for that:

```
{% for person in people | map ('combine', { "title": 'M.'} ) -%}
  Hello  {{ person.title ~ ' ' ~ person.forename ~ ' ' ~ person.name }}
{% endfor -%}
```

And i can also add a test to choose the correct title:

```
{% for person in people | map ('combine', { "title": 'Mr'}  if 1==1 else { "title": 'Ms'}) -%}
  Hello  {{ person.title ~ ' ' ~ person.forename ~ ' ' ~ person.name }}
{% endfor -%}
```

But i have been unable to acces to the current `person`, i have tried thinks like `person.gender=='M'`, `self.gender=='M'`, `this.gender=='M'`, but without success.

Is there any way to do it ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my question since i finally have found a way to do it.

The key is to filter the people array with selectattr, then to apply the combine and do it again for the rest of the array.

```
{% for person in   people | selectattr("gender", "equalto", "F") | map('combine', { 'title': 'Ms' }) + 
                   people | selectattr("gender", "equalto", "M") | map('combine', { 'title': 'Mr' })      -%}
  Hello  {{  person.title }} {{ person.forename }} {{  person.name }}
{% endfor -%}
```

The for statement is of course more complex, but the loop body is straightforward.